# Coloring Strings in VarDumper

Tags: symfony, var-dump

When I output my logs in the `dump()` function using [VarDumper](https://github.com/symfony/var-dumper), Is there any way I can change the color of some of the text in the strings that it outputs? I know this isn't the standard use of the function but If i want to view logs in an easy to read way Vardumper is great for this.

For instance, the strings are entirely green.  If i add *any* HTML, it gets directly written to the page and not styled at all.  I can't make text bold or anything.

Is there any workaround of this at all?  In Unix I know I can escape the echo and write a number and it will color the following text red, Is there anything Like that I can do?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use [Dumpers](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/var_dumper/advanced.html#dumpers), specifically the `HtmlDumper` to fiddle with the formatting of the HTML output.

```
$dumper = new HtmlDumper();
$dumper->setTheme('light');
$dumper->dump('Hello World!');
```

I imagine you could then extends the [HtmlDumper Class](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/4.3/src/Symfony/Component/VarDumper/Dumper/HtmlDumper.php) to add your own themes.